# kSoap2 throwing http 404 not found error on transport.call(url)

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, wcf-binding, android-ksoap2

I'm working on calling a wdsl web service from an android app using kSoap2 v3.1 and I keep getting the not found error. I've verified that the URL, Soap_Action, Method_Name, and namespace are all correct. I've also been looking around at other reasons why this error is being thrown and no other solutions are working for me. The webservice is being hosted locally and I'm debugging locally. I've made sure that the service is working using WC FStorm and the WCFTestClient and all calls made are executed without any problem. I don't think that anything is wrong with my app so I've looked into different ways to do the bindings in the service.

Here is the App.config for the webservice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<configSections>

  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

   </configSections>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" />
 </system.web>   
   <system.serviceModel>    
   <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="LocalWCF.Service1Behavior" name="LocalWCF.LocalWCF">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/LocalWCF/LocalWCF.LocalWCF.svc/" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="LocalWCF.ILocalWCF" >          
        <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />          
         </identity>        
    </endpoint>        
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/LocalWCF/LocalWCF.LocalWCF.svc/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="LocalWCF.Service1Behavior">

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>      
  </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
   <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
 </entityFramework>
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TradersWallDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.TradersWallDB.csdl|res://*/Data.TradersWallDB.ssdl|res://*/Data.TradersWallDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=RADSTATION1000;initial catalog=TradersWallDB;persist security info=True;user id=DefaultUser;password=testpass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
 <startup>
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  </configuration>
```

And here is the method in the app that calls the service

```
public long SendUser(User newUser)
{
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ILocalWCF/AddUserToDB/";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "AddUserToDb";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/LocalWCF/LocalWCF.LocalWCF.svc";
    final String email = newUser.email;
    final String userName= newUser.userName;

    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("userName", userName);
        request.addProperty("email", email);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        /**
        Element e = new Element();
        e.setName("To");
        e.setNamespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing");
        e.addChild(Node.TEXT,URL);

        Element e1 = new Element();
        e1.setName("Action");
        e1.setNamespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing");
        e1.addChild(Node.TEXT,SOAP_ACTION);

        envelope.headerOut = new Element[]{e,e1};
        */

        HttpTransportSE transport= new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        return Long.parseLong(response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've been stuck on this and have gone through a bunch of fixes but this is my last little hurdle. Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the trailing `/` in the address attribute in the service config's endpoint - i.e., `http://localhost/LocalWCF/LocalWCF.LocalWCF.svc` instead of `http://localhost/LocalWCF/LocalWCF.LocalWCF.svc/`.  Chances are the trailing slash is throwing things off.